# split string and numeric in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, regex, split

i have a string like,  "ABCD000215" i need split into string and numeric separately. I need to add break between the string and number

my code

```
<div class="box-label">{{item.stringVal}}</div>
```

The result will be like this

```
 ABCD
 000215
```

Comment: Have you tried to create a filter? I think they suit your needs best. https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09

Comment: `"ABCD000215".match(/\d+|[a-z]+/ig)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an Angular [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

Html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
    <div class="box-label">{{main.stringVal | splitStringAndNumber}}</div> 
</body>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('angularApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function() {
  this.stringVal = "ABCD12334234";
});

app.filter('splitStringAndNumber', function($filter){
    return function(string){
      var matches = string.match(/\d+|[a-z]+/ig);
      return matches.join('\r\n');
    };
});
```

Here's an example: https://plnkr.co/edit/G6ltclPLxRpijruYjcqy?p=preview

Comment: Not sure what happened there, it seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[a-z]+|\d+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fW0dI7/1)

**Explanation:**
`+`: One or more [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wV7cV2/1)
`|`: Alternation / OR operand [sample](https://regex101.com/r/uQ0iC0/1)
`\`: Escapes a special character [sample](https://regex101.com/r/aM5iM5/1)

Answer (score 0):

Here Check This Plunker I Created .. Hope this helps :)

```
 var app = angular.module('app', []).filter('checkmark', function() {

   return function(input, regex) {
      var patt = new RegExp(regex);      
      var out = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
          if(patt.test(input[i]))
              out.push(input[i]);
      }      
    return out;
  };
});

app.controller('ctrl',function($scope){
  $scope.a = "ABCD000215";

});



<p>Sum: {{a | checkmark : '^[0-9]*$'}}</p>

    <p>Sum: {{a | checkmark : '^[a-zA-Z]*$'}}</p>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/irKm0idyEy7jglYz5e6R?p=preview